# Result of Custom WP_Query appears on 404 Page (but result are found!)

Tags: php, wp-query, 404-error

I wrote a custom search page. It was working well then I added additional changes, now I got 404-Result-problem. The problem keep there even I did revert (I have backup) and I cleared the cache. I'm not sure if it's because of Wordpress update i ran today.

So I want to find out what wrong here since I don't know why I got "404 Not Found"-Page with "Sorry, keine Beiträge gefunden" (which means "Sorry, no posts found") but there I see the result (so its actually fine!). Because of 404-Page my Result-Page (as I said its found) looks broken.

I just found out: If I keep the "Name" field empty, then the page result is fine. But as soon I enter name (which searchs in title of pages) pages are found but I got 404-Page.

Here my code, maybe I oversaw something important?

```
<?php

class FlohSearch
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));
        add_shortcode('floh_search', array($this, 'shortcode_handler'));
    }

    public function init()
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['nonce_custom_form']))
        {
            if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce_custom_form'], 'handle_custom_form'))
            {
                die('You are not authorized to perform this action.');
            } else
            {
                $error = null;
                if (empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['workingLanguage']) && empty($_POST['workingArea']))
                {
                    $error = new WP_Error('empty_error', __('Please enter search request.', 'floh'));
                    wp_die($error->get_error_message(), __('FlohSearch Error', 'floh'));
                }
                else
                {
                  $search_names = explode(' ', $_POST['name']);
                  $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_parent' => $_POST['district'],
                    'title_filter' => $_POST['name'],
                    'meta_query' => array(
                      'relation' => 'AND',
                      array(
                        'key' => 'arbeitssprache',
                        'value' => $_POST['workingLanguage'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                      ),
                      array(
                        'key' => 'fachgebiet',
                        'value' => $_POST['workingArea'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                      )
                    )
                  );
                  add_filter('posts_where', 'title_filter',10,2);
                  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                  remove_filter('posts_where', 'title_filter',10);

                  // The Loop
                  if( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    echo '<div id="flohresult">';
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                      $query->the_post();
                      $link = wp_get_shortlink();
                      echo '<div id="item">';
                      echo '  <div id="item-header"><h3><a href="'.$link.'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
                      echo '    <div id="item-row">';
                      echo '      <div id="item-thumbnail">';
                      echo '        <a href="'.$link.'">';
                      the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                      echo '        </a></div>';
                      echo '        <div id="item-excerpt">';
                      echo '          <h4>Wohnort:</h4>'.get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'wohnort', true);
                      echo '          <h4>Arbeitssprachen:</h4>'.get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'arbeitssprache', true);
                      echo '          <h4>Fachgebiete:</h4>'.get_post_meta($query->post->ID, 'fachgebiet', true);
                      echo '        </div>';
                      echo '      </div>';
                      echo '  </div>';
                      echo '</div>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                  } else {
                    echo '<div id="flohresult">';
                      echo '<h3>Kein Ergebnis mit folgende Suchfilter:</h3>';
                      echo '<p>Name: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
                      echo '<p>Bezirk: ';
                      switch($_POST['district'])
                      {
                        case 65:
                          echo 'Mittelfranken';
                          break;
                        case 361:
                          echo 'Niederbayern';
                          break;
                        case 363:
                          echo 'Oberbayern';
                          break;
                        case 355:
                          echo 'Oberfranken';
                          break;
                        case 359:
                          echo 'Oberpfalz';
                          break;
                        case 365:
                          echo 'Schwaben';
                          break;
                        case 357:
                          echo 'Unterfranken';
                          break;
                        default:
                          echo 'Ausserhalb Bayerns';
                      }
                      '</p>';
                      echo '<p>Arbeitssprache: '.$_POST['workingLanguage'].'</p>';
                      echo '<p>Fachbereich: '.$_POST['workingArea'].'</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function shortcode_handler($atts)
    {
        return "<form method='post' action=''>
            <p>
              Name:</br>
              <input name='name' type='text' value='' />
            </p>
            <p>
              Bezirk:</br>
              <select name='district'>
                <option value='65'>Mittelfranken</option>
                <option value='361'>Niederbayern</option>
                <option value='363'>Oberbayern</option>
                <option value='355'>Oberfranken</option>
                <option value='359'>Oberpfalz</option>
                <option value='365'>Schwaben</option>
                <option value='357'>Unterfranken</option>
                <option value='421'>Ausserhalb Bayerns</option>
              </select>
            </p>
            <p>
              Arbeitssprache:</br>
              <input name='workingLanguage' type='text' value='' />
            </p>
            <p>
              Fachgebiet:</br>
              <input name='workingArea' type='text' value='' />
            </p>
            " . wp_nonce_field('handle_custom_form', 'nonce_custom_form') . "
            <input id='button' type='submit' value='Submit'/>
            </form>";
    }
}
$FlohSearch = new FlohSearch();
?>
```

And here the part in function.php of child-theme:

```
function title_filter($where, $wp_query)
{
    global $wpdb;
    if($search_term = $wp_query->get( 'title_filter' )){
        $search_term = $wpdb->esc_like($search_term);
        $search_term = ' \'%' . $search_term . '%\'';
        $title_filter_relation = 'AND';
        $where .= ' '.$title_filter_relation.' ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE '.$search_term;
    }
    return $where;
```

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Floh

Answer (score 0):

I found out its because I used a Input with name='name' which caused this issue. I believe the name 'name' is a keyword in wordpress/php. I replaced the 'name' to 'personname' then it works as charm.

```
...
 <input name='personname' type='text' value='' />
...
$_POST['gsdname']   // multiple time in my code
...
```

Best regards
Floh